# Eclipse EMF - Synchronize common model data

Tags: model, dsl, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf, graphiti

I would like to know how to synchronize data of model elements (attributes, references, etc) which are common to several meta-models.

Basically, I am building a DSL editor using Eclipse Graphiti that consists of several meta-models which can be independently modified. These meta-models, say X, Y, and Z, contain their own model elements as well as common classes and attributes, say class "MyClass" with attributes a and b.

The issue is when I edit the attributes of "MyClass" based on meta-model X, I would like to see any changes made to be synchronized/replicated to the other model data for Y and Z.

Looking forward to your help/suggestions.

Comment: So you want to synchronize the ecore metamodel or the values that you put in your EMF Objects?

Comment: @Pushkar 
I need to synchronize the values of EMF objects. So I have common classes (with their attributes) in several meta models. Based on my example, if I open the editor that represents meta model X and modify attributes 'a' and 'b' of 'MyClass', I want these changes to be updated to the same attributes 'a' and 'b' of 'MyClass'in my other meta models Y and Z - I don't want to open the editor for meta models Y and Z and re-do the changes again.